# Virtual LAN configuration

Tags: vlan

[image]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYDh2.jpg) Suppose i want to transmit a frame from IP 179.58.10.101 to 179.58.20.11,
How forwarding tables are built for each switch in newly configured Virtual LAN when all devices are just turned on? All PCs were configured with static IP address.

Answer (score 1):

A switch doesn't particularly care of, nor make note of, whatever IP addresses are in use on frames traversing the switch ports.  A switch only cares about the MAC address.  Every time a frame is *received* on a particular switch port, the Switch learns the frame's *source MAC address*.   How this works with VLANs, is that **each VLAN on a switch has its own, independent MAC address table**.

Given the following topology, a packet from HostA to HostB would bounce between each switch, going from VLAN to VLAN.  The switch, upon receiving the frame, would learn each time from the *source MAC address* of each frame received, on each VLAN, on each Port.

[image: Frame Bouncing between two Switches]

In the end, after a packet had gone from HostA to HostB and back, the fully populated MAC address tables would look like this:

**TOP Switch:**

```
VLAN    PORT    MAC Address
10      1       aaaa.aaaa.aaaa
10      3       bbbb.bbbb.bbbb
30      5       aaaa.aaaa.aaaa
30      7       bbbb.bbbb.bbbb
50      9       aaaa.aaaa.aaaa
50      11      bbbb.bbbb.bbbb
70      13      aaaa.aaaa.aaaa
70      15      bbbb.bbbb.bbbb
```

**BOTTOM Switch:**

```
VLAN    PORT    MAC Address
20      3       aaaa.aaaa.aaaa
20      5       bbbb.bbbb.bbbb
40      7       aaaa.aaaa.aaaa
40      9       bbbb.bbbb.bbbb
60      11      aaaa.aaaa.aaaa
60      13      bbbb.bbbb.bbbb
80      15      aaaa.aaaa.aaaa
80      17      bbbb.bbbb.bbbb
```

*NOTE1: I intentionally didn't put IP addresses on my hosts, because they are entirely inconsequential and would not affect the behavior described above whatsoever.*

*NOTE2: Port 3 of the TOP switch is in VLAN 10.  Port 3 of the BOTTOM switch is in VLAN 20.  But we'll assume these are both **access ports** and therefore the traffic leaves the switchports untagged.  As such, the BOTTOM switch doesn't know of (or care about) VLAN 10, and the TOP switch doesn't know of (or care about) VLAN 20.*

---

Yikes, your question changed drastically.  I'm going to leave my original anwer, because I still think it is relevant to your (new) question.  But to properly answer it, I had to add to your picture:

[image]
Before you can really understand how the Switches learn source MAC addresses, you have to learn how the packet travels from HostA (on the left), to HostB (on the right).  I put numbers at each position of the packet and the direction it is traveling to get to HostB.  The Src/Dst IP/MAC at each position would be as follows:

```
** Position 1 **
Src IP : 179.58.10.101          Src MAC: aaaa.aaaa.aaaa
Dst IP : 179.58.20.11           Dst MAC: eeee.eeee.eeee

** Position 2 **
Src IP : 179.58.10.101          Src MAC: aaaa.aaaa.aaaa
Dst IP : 179.58.20.11           Dst MAC: eeee.eeee.eeee

** Position 3 **
Src IP : 179.58.10.101          Src MAC: eeee.eeee.eeee
Dst IP : 179.58.20.11           Dst MAC: bbbb.bbbb.bbbb

** Position 4 **
Src IP : 179.58.10.101          Src MAC: eeee.eeee.eeee
Dst IP : 179.58.20.11           Dst MAC: bbbb.bbbb.bbbb

** Position 5 **
Src IP : 179.58.10.101          Src MAC: eeee.eeee.eeee
Dst IP : 179.58.20.11           Dst MAC: bbbb.bbbb.bbbb
```

If you take this information, and map out what the switches are doing at each step, you would end up with MAC address table as below for each switch:

```
** Switch1 MAC Address Table **
Port facing HostA   - VLAN 10 - aaaa.aaaa.aaaa
Port facing Router  - VLAN 10 - eeee.eeee.eeee (not learned until HostB responds)
Port facing Router  - VLAN 20 - eeee.eeee.eeee
Port facing Switch3 - VLAN 20 - bbbb.bbbb.bbbb (not learned until HostB responds)

** Switch3 MAC Address Table **
Port facing Switch1 - VLAN 20 - eeee.eeee.eeee
Port facing HostB   - VLAN 20 - bbbb.bbbb.bbbb (not learned until HostB responds)
```

*(I provided what the switch would learn on the return path when HostB responds to HostA as well, but if you are only interested in how the switches would populate with a packet from HostA to HostB ONLY, then please ignore those lines)*

Comment: i have edited my question. can you please tell me what will happen when all the devices are turned on for first time. I think no switches will have forwarding table.

Comment: This scenario remains same when no switches will have forwarding table? If ARP is used to find the destination MAC address, who will send that request? Router or switch1?

Comment: On VLAN 10, HostA will send the ARP **for the MAC address of the Router** (which is presumably configured as HostA's default gateway).  The ARP Request will be *flooded* by the switches throughout all of VLAN 10.   On VLAN 20, the **Router will ARP for HostB's MAC address**, and (just as before) the Switches will forward this ARP Request throughout the entire VLAN 20 domain.   Remember, switches do not initiate ARP to forward traffic -- they either already know the location of the destination MAC address, or they flood the frame out all ports.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing Eddie left out is what happens when the table is empty, or otherwise has no destination port for a given MAC. In that case, the packet is *unicast flood* to all ports; it doesn't know where the frame belongs, so it's sent everywhere.

Comment: In the unicast flooding, ARP request is to be sent to all computer?

Comment: arp requests are *broadcasts*, so they go everywhere anyway.

Comment: When switch1 will receive the response of arp request, it will send the original data frame to router or directly to switch 3?

Comment: ARP will not cross VLANs.  Switch1 will flood/forward the ARP Request out all ports in VLAN 10 (except the port it came in on).  There will be a second ARP, initiated by the Router, on VLAN20 in order to find HostB's MAC address.